# Prevent users from entering a value greater than 2 digits in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form field to get the month from the user.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="MM" size="2" name="month">
```

I need the field to accept only 2 digits. I tried Form validation, but it allows the user to enter more than 2 digits and then display the validation message. I don't need any validation messages for the field, but the user should be restricted to enter only 2 digits max. Is there a way we can do this using jquery?

Comment: I'd suggest enforcing a maximum of 12, rather than a maximum input length of two characters if you're wanting a numeric representation of the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="MM" size="2" name="month" maxlength="2>
```

The `maxlength` attribute;

`<input type="text" placeholder="MM" size="2" maxlength="2" name="month">`

It limits the amount of text you can enter by straight up not allowing you to type more.

EDIT: added snippet

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is using the `type='number'` attribute and setting `max='12'`:

```
<input type='number' max='12' min='1'>
```

#### SNIPPET

```css
input {
  width: 4ex;
  padding: 0 1px;
}
input:last-of-type {
  width: 6.5ex;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter Date</legend>
  <label>Month:</label>
  <input type='number' max='12' min='1'>

  <label>Day:</label>
  <input type='number' max='31' min='1'>

  <label>Year:</label>
  <input type='number' max='3000' min='2016'>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: why would you use `99` if ther's only 12 months? :)

Comment: Oh, I thought we are going by Jupiter's calendar.:P Updating to conform to terran time.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP said they want it only to accept 2 digits; not just show validation messages when more than 2 are entered. This answer lets you add as many digits as you want, but would fail validation if you do..

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out, whenever the user presses the key down it will check the lenght and then trim the extra chars if there are any:

```
$("input").keydown(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.length > 2) {
        value = value.substring(0, 2);
        $(this).val(value);
    }
});
```